# Gitlab include yml - access denied

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two (actually 4) projects within GitLab, who are also within the same group.

[image: The projects within this group]
*TimerApp should include `.yml` files from Pipelines*

One project should just hold different `.yml` files, as kind of pipeline templates.

However, including the pipeline within the second project leads to "lint" problems. It appears, that the access is denied.

[image]
*As you can see, either the file is not found or access is denied*

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve that. Especially, because two projects within the same group shouldn't have this issue, right?

The obvious problem could have been, that the file was just not there. However, if I try the url etc. it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includefile), you have to use the project name only, not the whole URL.

```yaml
include:
  - project: 't9224/pipelines'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.pages.yml'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out perfect. Somehow I've read the documentation several times but overlooked exactly that part.

Answer (score 1):

`project:` should just include the namespace and project, not the entire URL.

```yaml
include:
  - project: mynamespace/myproject
    # ...
```

As long as your user account has membership to the specified group or project, there should be no access denied issues.